# findViewById() in OnActivityResult function causes crash

Tags: android, android-intent, findviewbyid, onactivityresult

In onActivityResult function I create layout and button in this layout. And when I press the button, I want to edit data in it by calling a new activity. I received data from new activity and want to find button by id to apply changes. But function findViewById causes crash of my application. How can I fix it?

This is part of my code:

```
if(requestCode == EditingMedicine)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            int _id = data.getIntExtra(AddEditMedicineActivity.Id, -1);
            String medName = data.getStringExtra(AddEditMedicineActivity.medName);
            String medTime = data.getStringExtra(AddEditMedicineActivity.medTime);              
            Button btn = (Button)findViewById(_id);
            btn.setText(Html.fromHtml(medName + " <br/>" + medTime));
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want some help, you should also add the error log.

Answer (score 0):

The button does not exists in the new activity xml . hence , findviewbyid crashes

Answer (score 0):

For an `Activity` you need to set a `layout` in the `onCreate` method , make sure that you have button on the layout you referenced to